# How to sort and get the min & max Value from an Array?

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

I got 2 Arrays

```
//each array contains 8 values
$ids = Array(1441, 1313, 1123, 1316, 1313, 1313, 1123, 1567);
//each id has a value in $data array
$data = Array(2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 4, 2, 9);


//here is my problem: 

$max_data = array_product($data); //but not all values from $data only these:
$ids = [1441,1123,1316,1313,1567]; //these are the ids with highest data.
echo $max_data; //result must be 2880 (2 * 8 * 4 * 5 * 9)
$min_data = array_product($data); //and now
$ids = [1441,1313,1316,1123,1567]; //these are the ids with lowest data.
echo $max_data; //result must be 432 (2 * 3 * 4 * 2 * 9)
```

I hope, i was able to explain my problem.

Thanks.

---

**Solved it.**

*I have made a function to get max and min. I would like to get better answers, thanks!*

```
<?php

$ids = Array(1441, 1313, 1123, 1316, 1313, 1313, 1123, 1567);           
$data = Array(2, 3, 8, 4, 5, 4, 2, 9);

function getMaxData($ids, $data)
{
    (int)$_total = 1;
    array_multisort($ids, $data, SORT_DESC);

    foreach(array_unique($ids) as $key => $value)
        $_total *= $data[$key];

    return $_total;
}

function getMinData($ids, $data)
{
    (int)$_total = 1;
    array_multisort($ids, $data, SORT_ASC);

    foreach(array_unique($ids) as $key => $value)
        $_total *= $data[$key];

    return $_total;
}

echo "Max: ".getMaxData($ids, $data)."<br />";
echo "Min: ".getMinData($ids, $data)."<br />";

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correctly but isn't associative arrays what you need?

```
$foo = Array(2 => 1441, 3 => 1313 .... )
```

http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.array.php